# How can I toggle between two blocks on button press with a command block?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to change a concrete block from red to green and vice-versa, when players click a button. How can I achieve this with a command block?

Comment: I assume you mean that the player clicks the button, and when they click the button, the color of the concrete toggles? So the first time they click it, it turns green, they click again, it turns red. Is that what you’re asking for?

Comment: yes is what i was trying to explain xD on hard way hehehe
do you know how to make this ?

Comment: Answer incoming :) Welcome to the arcade!

Comment: I already make =) is not the way i want but works 

I create a switch to power a block with torch on top on another side of the block i got a command block to replace red to green concrete and on top of this torch i have opposite command block to change from red to green...

please if you make this only with commands block let me know =) i give you the correct answer xD